# Pandas 0.8 read_csv not recognizing 'dtype' parameter

Tags: python, pandas, csv, types

I'm trying to read in a csv file using pandas (0.8.1) using the dtype parameter and am having an error.

My csv file structure looks like this:

```
"USAF","WBAN","STATION NAME","CTRY","FIPS","STATE","CALL","LAT","LON","ELEV(.1M)","BEGIN","END"
"006852","99999","SENT","SW","SZ","","","+46817","+010350","+14200","",""
"007005","99999","CWOS 07005","","","","","-99999","-999999","-99999","20120127","20120127"
```

The reason I need to specify the dtype is because the first two columns `USAF`,`WBAN` need to be string since they sometimes start with zeros, and when I read regularly it converts a number like 0006852 into 6852.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.io.parsers.read_csv("Station Codes.csv", dtype={'USAF': np.str, 'WBAN': np.str})
```

results in the following error:

```
TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'
```

I don't understand why it's saying that its an unexpected keyword argument when I see the documentation here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dtype` argument was [introduced in 0.10](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew.html#file-parsing-new-features).
*Upgrade to [the latest stable release](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html) for the latest and greatest features and bug fixes.*

Comment: Thanks that was it I was on 0.8.1. Still doesn't like the np.str but that's for another question :/

Comment: I tried that and was still getting the same error. New question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16929056/pandas-read-csv-dtype-leading-zeros