# How can I make sure Pandas does not interpret a numeric string as a number in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have code that reads a CSV like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd

csv_path = 'test.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, delimiter=';', quotechar='"',
                 decimal=',', encoding="ISO-8859-1", dtype={'FOO': str})
df.FOO = df.FOO.map(lambda n: n.zfill(6))
```

and I get

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'zfill'
```

so obviously, Pandas interpreted the column `FOO` as a number. It is numeric, but I don't want to interpret it as a number

(I know that `df.FOO = df.FOO.map(lambda n: str(n).zfill(6))` makes the problem go away, but I would like to know why this problem occurs in the first place.)

I use pandas 0.20.3.

### Example CSV

```
FOO;BAR
01,23;4,56
1,23;45,6
;987
```

Comment: `dtype={'FOO': str}` should do it. Try `converters={'FOO': str}`

Comment: Can't reproduce it using Pandas 0.20.3. Try to use `{'FOO': 'object'}`

Comment: Related and probable dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988526/pandas-reading-csv-as-string-type

Comment: @EdChum I don't think it is a duplicate. I only skimmed over it, but in my case the problem is an empty cell. This looks like a Pandas bug.

Comment: See https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17810

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The problem is the empty cell.**

The line

```
df.FOO = df.FOO.fillna(value="")
```

gives the desired behavior, but this seems to be a quite dirty solution.

I'm not sure weather this is a bug or desired behaviour: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17810

Comment: This is a fine solution (answered on the github issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17810#issuecomment-335096780)