# can I make pandas convert dtypes before doing dataframe operations?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a pandas dataframe with multiple dtypes and I want to add data from another which might have other types. Is there an easy way to make pandas convert the types or raise an error when, for instance, concatenating the dataframes?

```py
import pandas as pd

old = pd.DataFrame({'one':[1,2,3],'two':[100,200,300]}).astype({'one':'int8', 'two':'Int16'})
new = pd.DataFrame({'one':['11','22','33'],'two':['110','220','330']})

(old.dtypes == new.dtypes).all() # False

# a normal pd.concat([old, new]) at this point would result in 'object' dtypes for
# both columns. I want something like

result = coercive_concat([old, new])
(old.dtypes == result.dtypes).all() # True
(result.dtypes == new.dtypes).all() # False

# and it should raise an error when it can't coerce the types

odd = pd.DataFrame({'one':['eleventeen','22','33'],'two':['110','220','330']})
result = coercive_concat([old, odd]) # Error
```

Comment: use `astype()` method:  `pd.concat([new.astype(int), old])` new check their dtypes of your sample dataframe

Comment: `new.astype(dict(zip(new.columns, old.dtypes.values)))` raises an error for me. I don't want a generic `int`, I need the types to be identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the current version of my solution (old version at the end of this answer). The function below handles null values and booleans. Nulls are a pain because pandas will switch to `float` when appending `np.nan` even for pandas `Int` types (nulls must be `np.NA` to preserve the column type). Booleans are a problem when reading boolean fields out of text files because the nonempty string `"False"` is boolean `True`.

```py
import pandas as pd

def coerce_types(coerce, template, insert_columns=True):
    '''
    coerce one pandas Series or DataFrame into the same data types as 
    another. This function was initially required because pandas cannot 
    convert string values directly to pd.Int types, but pd.Int types are
    the only integer types that have a null value in pandas. The
    solution is to first convert to numpy.int types by using lower case
    names for integer dtypes in DataFrame.astype() and then convert to
    any other type.
    See https://stackoverflow.com/q/67646300/875343
    '''
    
    coerce = coerce.copy()
    
    if (type(coerce) == pd.Series):
        if (type(template) != pd.Series):
            raise TypeError('if object to coerce has type pd.Series '
                            'then template must have type pd.Series')
        try:
            coerce = coerce.astype(str(template.dtypes))
        except:
            whereNaN = coerce.isna()
            coerce = coerce.fillna(0)

            coerce = coerce.astype(str(template.dtypes).lower())
            coerce = coerce.astype(str(template.dtypes))

            coerce = coerce.mask(whereNaN, pd.NA)
    else:
        
        if not all([l in template.columns for l in coerce.columns]):
            missing_cols = [l for l in coerce.columns
                            if l not in template.columns]
            raise ValueError('Every column in dataframe to coerce must '
                             'exist in template dataframe. Column '
                             'label(s) {} do not exist in the template.'
                             .format(missing_cols))

        common_cols = [l for l in coerce.columns if l in template.columns]
        
        if insert_columns and not all([l in coerce.columns
                                       for l in template.columns]):

            for i in range(len(template.columns)):
                label = template.columns[i]
                if label not in common_cols:
                    coerce.insert(i, label, pd.NA)

            c = template.columns

        else:
            c = common_cols

        coerce = coerce[c]
        
        if 'is_directed' in coerce.columns:
            print(coerce['is_directed'])

        # non-empty strings are boolean True (the string "False" is 
        # truthy) so check for columns of type 'object' that need to be 
        # coerced to boolean and then map "true" and "false" to their
        # boolean values (case insensitive).
        types_to_coerce = pd.Series(coerce.dtypes, index=c)
        template_types = pd.Series(template[c].dtypes, index=c)

        where_template_bool = (template_types == bool)
        if where_template_bool.any():

            bool_labels = template_types.loc[where_template_bool].index.array
            where_coerce_also_obj = (types_to_coerce[bool_labels] == 'object')

            if where_coerce_also_obj.any():

                labels = where_coerce_also_obj.index.array

                bool_map = {'true':True, 'false':False}
                mapper = lambda x: x.str.lower().map(bool_map)

                coerce.loc[:, labels] = coerce[labels].apply(mapper)
        
        if 'is_directed' in coerce.columns:
            print(coerce['is_directed'])

        try:
            coerce = coerce.astype(dict(zip(coerce.columns,
                                            template[c].dtypes.array)))
        except:
            whereNaN = coerce.isna()
            coerce = coerce.fillna(0)

            lower_case_types = template[c].dtypes.astype(str).str.lower().array
            coerce = coerce.astype(dict(zip(coerce.columns, lower_case_types)))
            coerce = coerce.astype(dict(zip(coerce.columns,
                                            template[c].dtypes.array)))

            coerce = coerce.mask(whereNaN, pd.NA)
    
    return coerce
```

---

### previous answer

The answer from Anurang Dabas is correct but it does not handle null values. Since pandas often defaults to numpy `np.nan` (which does not convert to pandas `Int` types) instead of the newer pandas `pd.NA` type (which does), applying that answer alone will throw errors for null values in some cases, for instance when a column has type `'object'` with some `np.nan` values and you try to convert to a `pd.Int` type. The function below handles `np.nan` values.

```
import pandas as pd
def coerce_types(change=None, like=None):
    if (type(change) == pd.Series):
        try:
            change = change.astype(str(like.dtypes))
        except:
            whereNaN = change.isna()
            change = change.fillna(0)
            change = change.astype(str(like.dtypes).lower())
            change = change.astype(str(like.dtypes))
            change = change.mask(whereNaN, pd.NA)
    else:
        try:
            change = change.astype(dict(zip(change.columns, like.dtypes.values)))
        except:
            whereNaN = change.isna()
            change = change.fillna(0)
            change = change.astype(dict(zip(change.columns, like.dtypes.astype(str).str.lower().values)))
            change = change.astype(dict(zip(change.columns, like.dtypes.values)))
            change = change.mask(whereNaN, pd.NA)
    return change
```

note that this will convert all null values in the dataframe to `pd.NA` and that is not equivalent to `np.nan`. You will need to modify this code if you want to preserve the null types from the original dataframe. Example with dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

old_types = ['Int8', 'float', 'Int32', 'object']
old_data = pd.DataFrame({'a':1, 'b':1e6, 'c':3, 'd':'value'}, index=[0])
old_data = old_data.astype(dict(zip(old_data.columns, old_types)))
all(old_data.dtypes.values == ['Int8', 'float64', 'Int32', 'object'])
# True

new_data = pd.DataFrame({'a':2, 'b':'555', 'c':4}, index=[0])
all(new_data.dtypes.values == ['int64', 'object', 'int64'])
# True

naive_result = old_data.append(new_data)
all(old_data.dtypes == naive_result.dtypes)
# False

correct_result = coerce_types(naive_result, old_data)
all(old_data.dtypes == correct_result.dtypes)
# True
all(correct_result.dtypes.values == ['Int8', 'float64', 'Int32', 'object'])
# True
```

Example with series:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

old_data = pd.Series(['1', '2', np.nan, 4.0])

old_data.astype('Int8')
# TypeError: object cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype

old_data = coerce_types(old_data, pd.Series([], dtype='Int8'))
print(old_data)
'''
output:
0       1
1       2
2    <NA>
3       4
dtype: Int8
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
new=new.astype(dict(zip(new.columns, old.dtypes.astype(str).str.lower().values)))
```

Now if you print `new.dtypes` you will get:

```
one     int8
two    int16
dtype: object
```

Comment: I'll be damned. It didn't occur to me that pandas would be able to coerce numpy integers but not pandas integers

Comment: you can't convert `string` directly to `'Int16' (pandas.Int8Dtype)` but you can convert `'int16'(numpy.int8)`  directly to `'Int16' (pandas.Int8Dtype)`

Comment: this is so helpful

Comment: so if you want exact same dtype then firstly execute `new=new.astype(dict(zip(new.columns, old.dtypes.astype(str).str.lower().values)))` after that execute `new=new.astype(dict(zip(new.columns, old.dtypes.values)))`

Answer (score 0):

There is way to treat every column data as string type during the reading of file or creating a dataframe by passing argument `dtype=str`

This will change NaN as "NULL" for null values

Here is a code snippet which changes the all dtypes as string

`df_read = pd.read_csv(savefile, dtype=str)`

May be you can go through this similar question asked in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988526/pandas-reading-csv-as-string-type/52156896) . Also , this behaviour varies little with version of pandas you are using. In newer pandas, the code snippet will work fine

I have modified your code little bit below

```
import pandas as pd

old = pd.DataFrame({'one':[1,2,3],'two':[100,200,300]}, dtype=str)
new = pd.DataFrame({'one':['11','22','33'],'two':['110','220','330']}, dtype=str)

print((old.dtypes == new.dtypes).all()) # This will return True as all data types are string now
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! Unfortunately I have a dataframe with multiple types, so I can't use a `dtype` keyword that way here. Also, you can see the `new` frame here already has `object` type. My goal is to keep the original dataframe unchanged and convert the new one.